# How to remove dollar format with regex

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am trying to remove the dollar format from the string '$1,109,889.23'. I tried using a regular expression with:

```
"[^\\d]"
```

but then I get the commas.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language are you using and what relevant function are you calling? Using that with some kind of `replaceAll()` method would probably work fine (though it would also remove the decimal, so something like `[^\d.]` might be better). For that matter, are you trying to remove the commas, too? I'm not quite sure from the way you phrased this.

Comment: I am using ColdFusion. [^\d.] works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using ColdFusion. The [^\d.] works great as eldarerathis  mentioned above.

```
   <cfset amt = '$1,109,889.23'>
   <cfset newAmt = ReReplace(amt, "[^\d.]", "","ALL") >
   <cfoutput>#newAmt#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a regex for this.

Just use [`lsParseCurrency`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/lsparsecurrency.html):

`numericValue = lsParseCurrency('$1,109,889.23');
writeOutput(numericValue);`

[Example on trycf.com](http://trycf.com/gist/e66813c4d297f24b41bb61a1b792405f/acf2016?theme=monokai) yields:

`1109889.23`

As per Leigh's commment below... if yer locale is something that doesn't use `,` and `.` for the thousands and decimal separators (respectively)... make sure to specify the locale too, eg:

`numericValue = lsParseCurrency('$1,109,889.23', 'en_us');`

Comment: True. Though best to specify locale en_US explicitly. Otherwise, it will use the currency rules of the current JVM locale (which may be different) and crash.

Comment: (Obviously not an issue if the jvm locale is already en_US ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Leigh. Updated to include that note.

Answer (score 3):

How about just doing a search and replace for `,` and `$`?

but if you're going to do it.

`[^\d.]+`

Comment: i know, i had to do it the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

Since `$` is a metacharacter in regex (it means "end of string" or "end of line", depending on the current settings), it needs to be escaped to `\$`. But why use a regex at all if it's just one fixed character?

Comment: Depends on the regex engine!  In JS the escape for `$` is `$$`.

Comment: What is JS? I've never seen `$$` used anywhere. But then I haven't seen everything.

Answer (score 0):

`[\d,.]+` would give you the number part. [Here](http://rubular.com/r/8am6ZFozby) is your example on Rubular.

Comment: this matches everything but the $ sign. i wanted to get rid of the commas as well, so [^\d.] worked great.

Comment: You wrote that you wanted to remove the dollar.

Answer (score 0):

Would this RegEx work for you?

```
^\$
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want, but it seems that in your example you would want to end up with "1,109,889.23".  If this is the case, why don't you simply select use `[\d,.\x20]+` (note the period is not escaped, as it is in character set, and note the \x20 to select spaces if they use that instead of commas) to select just the number.  If you want to select everything that is NOT part of the number, as your example indicates, then you would just search for `[^\d,.\x20]`.  This will work for any currency format, not just ones that use the dollar sign.  It will also allow multiple types of punctuation, such as allowing spaces instead of commas to separate multiple numbers.  However, I agree with Tim Pietzcker that a regular expression might not be the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

```
String newString = oldString.replaceAll("$", "");
```