# Regex to strip currency prefix AND any commas

Tags: regex

- `AUD 3,430.00` should become `3430.00`
- `AUD 1,322,213.12` should become `1322213.12`

Basically the requirements are:

1. Drop the currency prefix
2. Strip the number of any and all commas
3. Allow the single decimal point

`(?<=AUD ).*`

works only to remove the "AUD ".

How can I ammend this regex to also drop the comma?  Or is there a more elegant solution to achieve both?

Comment: Use `[^\d.]+` or `[^0-9.]+` to replace with an empty string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  feel free to suggest a complete solution and I will accept it

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Pure regex that would universally work with any programming language.

Comment: So, there is no answer then as there is no "pure" regex.

Comment: Javascript then.

Comment: Here is the regex I suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4348648/3832970

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way:

```js
let str_input = `AUD 1,322,213.12
AUD 3,430.00
AUD 1.1`;

let arr_input = str_input.split("\n");
let regex = /[\d.]+/g;
for(let i=0; i<arr_input.length; i++){
  let temp_str = arr_input[i];
  let match = temp_str.match(regex);
  let result = match.join("");
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm actually using a plugin field.  I cannot enter anything except Regex.  See [here](https://www.webscraper.io/documentation#text-selector).

Comment: How about this way: Use regex `(?<=AUD )[\d,.]+` get numbers, then treat with this number (example `1,322,213.12`) ?

Comment: I'm not really coding in an open environment that I can get and retreat numbers.  I'm stuck inside the GUI, which caters only to a single regex expression...

Comment: At its core my question is really asking can you skip a character.  All my searches so far lead to the conclusion that regex doesn't allow you to skip a character and match everything before and after it.  Do I stand corrected?

Comment: Yes, your number inputs has many part, so the way is have to concatenate the matched array to get the right result!